# Pytorch geometric for custom video dataset

Tags: video, dataset, pytorch-geometric, face

I have a set of video frames of human faces. I am using trying use GNN for predictions. Can I get insights into how to create the Dataset.

Structure of root:
`/root/ |-->` sub1`/ |-->` video1`/ |-->` frame_xy`....`

when processing, what would be the best way to save to the processing_dir for each subject
[``` sub1-video1``: [Data( ```frame1`,` adj1`,` y1`), Data(`frame2`,` adj2`,` y2`),....],` sub1_video2`: [Data(`frame1`,` adj1`,` y1`), Data(`frame2`,` adj2`,` y2`),....]

so on and so forth. Is there a better way to represent it? Can I be pointed towards an example dataset.

Thanks in advance, Regards

I have looked at the pytorch-geometric docs: https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/datasets.html

Also seen some example on github, here is one: https://github.com/deepfindr/gnn-project/blob/main/dataset.py